# Antipodal map on $ S^n $ homotopic to identity map if $n$ is odd

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to prove that the antipodal map from $S^n$ to $S^n$ is homotopic to the identity map if $n$ is odd. (I know it's actually true if and only if)

If I consider the map $ H(x,t) = (1-2t)x $, why doesn't this work? I don't really see how this  is any different if $n$ is odd or even. Is it continuous? Again, I don't see why it isn't

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Henning or Rasmus have explained to you, $H(x,t) = (1-2t)x$ fails to land within $S^n$ for $t\neq 0,1$. The usual trick to arrange that, namely redefine

$$
H(x,t) = \dfrac{(1-2t)x}{\| (1-2t)x \|}  \ ,
$$

doesn't work either because this new $H$ is not continuous for $t= \frac{1}{2}$.

If you want an specific homotopy from $\mathrm{id}_{S^{2n-1}}$ to $-\mathrm{id}_{S^{2n-1}}$, here is one.

Let's start with $n=1$. Let's think $S^1$ as the set of complex numbers $z \in \mathbb{C}$ of modulus 1: $\vert z \vert = 1$. Consider the map:

$$
H: S^1 \times I \longrightarrow S^1
$$

defined by

$$
H(z,t) = e^{i\pi t} z \ .
$$

This map is plainly continuous, its image lies on the sphere $\vert H(z,t) \vert = \vert e^{i\pi t}\vert \cdot \vert z \vert = \vert z \vert = 1$ and $H(z,0) = z$ and $H(z,1) = -z$. Hence, it may be the homotopy you were looking for, right?

For $n \geq 1$, exactly the same map works. Now you think your *odd* sphere $S^{2n-1}$ as being the subset of complex $n$-tuples $z = (z_1, \dots , z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ of modulus 1, $\vert z \vert = \sqrt{\vert z_1\vert^2 + \dots + \vert z_n\vert^2 } = 1$. And you consider the same map:

$$
H: S^{2n-1} \times I \longrightarrow S^{2n-1} \ .
$$

Namely,

$$
H(z,t) = e^{i\pi t} z = (e^{i\pi t} z_1 , \dots ,e^{i\pi t} z_n ) \ .
$$

The same proof we did for $n=1$ applies now and shows that $H$ is the desired homotopy.

Notice that, since we had to rely on complex numbers, this does not work for even spheres.

Finally, if you prefer, another way to write the map $H$ for $n=1$, now thinking $S^1$ as the set of points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\| (x,y) \| = 1$, could be

$$
H(x,y,t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (\pi t)  &  -\sin (\pi t) \\
\sin (\pi t)  &  \cos (\pi t)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}  \ .
$$

That is, we are rotating $(x,y)$ more and more, as $t$ increases, till we arrive at $(-x,-y)$. Notice that you need to be in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to do this: you couldn't rotate anything if we were talking about the "even" sphere $S^0 = \left\{ -1, +1\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and clearly there is no homotopy from $\mathrm{id}_{S^0}$ to $-\mathrm{id}_{S^0}$; that is, a path inside $S^0$, joining $-1$ and $+1$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by "Notice that, since we had to rely on complex numbers, this does not work for even spheres."

Comment: @TRY: try to do the same thing for an even sphere and see what happens!

Comment: @TRY. I think Mariano's answer is a great one.  :-)

Comment: @TRY. More precisely: where does an even sphere $S^{2n}$ -for instance, $S^0$, or $S^2$- "live"? Is it possible to construct a map like $H$ in those "ambient spaces"?

Comment: @AgustíRoig Is it because $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so we can only argue about $S^{n}$ for $n$ odd? (Thus it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for $n$ even)

Answer (score 7):

This follows easily from some algebraic topology, but you can:

1) prove that $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is path-connected (by hands)

2) $U(n)$ is path-connected, because they are homotopy-equivalent (equivalence being the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation.)

Every element of $U(2n)$ restricts to a map of $S^{2n-1}$. But both identity and antipodal maps lie in $U(n)$, so they are connected by a path. This will be your required homotopy.

Comment: Nice. But I think it suffices that for $n$ odd, both the antipodal and the identity lie in the connected $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{R})$. Also, I am curious about what is the "some algebraic topology" explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Your $H(x,t) = (1-2t)x$ fails to land within $S^n$ if $t$ is strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Hint: $-I\in SO(k)$ iff $k$ is even.

Answer (score 3):

Here is why your approach does not work:

If $t$ is not $0$ or $1$, then $(1-2t)$ will have modulus less than $1$. Hence $(1-2t)x$ does not belong to the sphere anymore. But if $H$ was a homotopy of maps to the sphere, it would take values on the sphere.