# About a proof using complex numbers that the antipodal map on $S^n$, $n$ odd, is homotopic to the identity map

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70671/antipodal-map-on-sn-homotopic-to-identity-map-if-n-is-odd/70716#70716) gives a solution to the following problem:

> Prove that antipodal map on $ S^n $ homotopic to identity map if $n$ is odd.

I am wondering:

> Why we had to rely on complex numbers in proving the above? And why this does not work for even spheres?"

Could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: I mean by "this" the proof that I shared its link. @EricWofsey

Comment: it is said in the link that we had relied on complex numbers @EricWofsey

Comment: You don't "have to" rely on complex numbers if you don't want to. There are perfectly viable proofs which do not involve complex numbers. But you gotta admit, that complex number proof is very pretty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof doesn't require complex numbers, but it certainly makes convenient writing down an explicit homotopy: $$H({\bf z}, t) := e^{\pi i t} {\bf z} .$$

This trick exploits the usual identification $\Bbb C^n \cong \Bbb R^{2n}$, and the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{2n}$, $\Bbb S^{2 n - 1}$ is odd-dimensional, so it does not apply to even-dimensional spheres.

Indeed, the statement is false for even-dimensional spheres, as the antipodal map for such spheres is a composition of an odd number of reflections, each of which has degree $-1$, so the antipodal map has degree $-1$.

Comment: Does the last paragraph contain something wrong? or may be I can not understand it :(

Comment: No, but it does use material outside the scope of the question as posed. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping